# Can I replace a 27.12MHZ by a 13.56MHZ Xtal on PN532

Tags: rfid, crystal, nfc

I have a prototype of NFC reader which is attached to my Board. But it seem it doesn't work ... the only change I made was the Xtal because I don't find 27.12MHZ.

Some people told me I can replace it if the hz was a multiple. The fact it don't work as expect. Is it normal ?

Comment: Go find the "some people" and tell them to fix it.  Otherwise you'll have to provide the right crystal actually specified for the part.

Comment: It is not beyond the realm of possibility that adjustments to the circuit could get a crystal of 1/3 of the needed frequency to oscillate on an overtone.  But 1/2 won't work as it must be an odd multiple.  1/2 would only work if there were normally an internal divider which could be disabled, or else an internal multiplier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Some people told me I can replace it if the hz was a multiple. The
>   fact it don't work as expect. Is it normal ?

Next time, better take a look at the data-sheet. The PN532 wants to see a 27.12MHZ xtal or external clock of the same frequency. You can't just pick a different clock-frequency.

You shouldn't have any problem finding the correct xtal online. They're cheap.